# Guid compare not working on linq where condition

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Here i pass a parameter named PId. Which will be compare with another table's PId. But i getting error when the query is binding query to ToList().

ERROR: "The specified type member 'PId' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

```
 public IList<Models.MyModel> GetDaraByPId(Guid PId)
            {
                var query = this._Repository.GetIQueryable();
                var list = query.Select(a => new Models.MyModel
                {
                    MyModelId = a.Id,
                    MyModelName = a.Name
                }).Where(f => f.PId == PId);
                return list.ToList();
            }
```

Comment: what does the var list returns...

Comment: Without where condition the var list returns.

Answer (score 2):

You must have a value of 'PId' (PId=a.PId), Then you are able to use this in a condition (Where(f => f.PId == PId)).

```
public IList<Models.MyModel> GetDaraByPId(Guid PId)
                {
                    var query = this._Repository.GetIQueryable();
                    var list = query.Select(a => new Models.MyModel
                    {
                        MyModelId = a.Id,
                        MyModelName = a.Name,
                        PId=a.PId
                    }).Where(f => f.PId == PId);
                    return list.ToList();
                }
```

Comment: an explanation as well is required

Comment: thanks @durlove it works now. I just miss out the PId on my select query.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too. Solution is that when you create a model constructor with condition by any parameter, the model must contain the Property which is for comparison. Here you miss 'PId' property of the model.